# Building a Ruby Gem Gem::Exception Error

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have made a new gem called hola as based on 
http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/
 tutorial but this error keeps occuring

This gem is located in the folder

> [gentoos@localhost hola]$ ls
>
> bin  data  doc  ext  hola-1.0.gem 
>   hola.gemspec  lib  Rakefile  tests

I run the command as instructed on the website

> gem install ./hola-1.0.gem

and this error occurs

> [gentoos@localhost hola]$ gem install ./hola-1.0.gem
>   ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
>       Unable to require openssl, install OpenSSL and rebuild ruby (preferred) or use non-HTTPS sources

I tried installing OpenSSL but still wouldn't

Comment: Are you using rbenv or rvm by any chance?

Comment: I don't know really but I googled it and is rvm the default ?

Comment: In your terminal, try `which rbenv` and `which rvm`. What output do you get for each?